# AWS Lambda and loading of reference data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm building a Lambda function in AWS that need to load reference data from a mysql database. There is no real issue right now as it very limited amount of data. But what is best practice here? Is there away to keep this data within Lambda (or some other similar functionality) so that I don't need to request it for every invocation of the function? I'm using Node js though I don't think that affects this question.

Many thanks,
Marcus

Comment: Depends on nature of the data. Is it static? Can you bundle it with source code? Is it large? Can you store it in parameter store? How often does it change? And what's wrong with getting it from mysql when needed?

Comment: Marcin, its rather static, seldom change data. Nothing wrong really with getting it from mysql apart from it has to do that at every invocation. If it was running on a server I would query once and keep in memory. I will probably leave it as is but was wondering if there is a more performance/cost efficient way where I could query once and store it in a to Lambda persistent store and maybe refresh on a daily basis. And the  desired result being shorter Lambda runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no build-in persistent storage** for lambda. Any data that you would like to keep reliably (not counting temporary persistence due to [lambda execution context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html)) between invocations is to store data outside of lambda itself.

You already store it in MySQL, but other popular choices are:

- [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html)
- S3
- EFS
- DynamoDB
- ElastiCache if you really need fast access to the data.

Since you already get the data from MySQL the only advantage of using SSM or DynamoDB would be that you can use **AWS API** to access and update them, or inspect/modify in AWS Console. You don't need to bundle any MySQL client with your function nor establish any connections to the database.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, that clears that up then. Will keep it as mysql for now, but am also looking at DynamoDB as a possibility. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @CaptainMJ No problem. Glad I could help.